# white space appearing below div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

**EDIT** [new jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aqg1khLs/14/) which successfully replicates the issue

I have this white space appearing below my div.

Shown here in 2 photos, one is scrolled down:

[image]

[image]

I want to get rid of the whitespace. The web page should take up 100% of the viewport when including the navigation bar, so it should change when the viewport changes, and it does, and it is the right size, but then there is some random white space below the page that you can scroll down to. The white space looks to be the exact size of the navigation bar. How do I get rid of that white space? Please attempt to on [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqg1khLs/14/)

code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button     class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#nav-content">
                    &#9776;
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">THE VEGAN REPOSITORY</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FIND</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ADD</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOGIN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">SIGN UP FREE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="landing-page" class="text-uppercase">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="row hidden-lg-up" style="height: 20%;">
            <div class="col-xs-3 flex-xs-middle">
                <img width="100" src="images/monster2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 offset-xs-6 flex-xs-middle">
                <img class="pull-xs-right" width="100" src="images/monster4.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="middle-row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 hidden-md-down flex-xs-top 
                flex-sm-middle">
                <img width="80%" src="images/monster2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 flex-xs-middle ">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <h5 class="display-6">the vegan repository</h5>
                    <h1 class="display-3">
                        find vegan stuff* near you.
                    </h1>
                                        <a id="try-now-button" class="with-border clickable" href="#search-filter-page">
                        <h5 class="text-center medium-text">try now</h5>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 hidden-md-down 
                flex-xs-top flex-sm-middle">
                <img class="pull-xs-right" width="80%" src="images/monster4.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:5%;">
            <h4 class="display-6 flex-xs-bottom">
                *Stuff like restaurants, meat alternatives, 
                dairy alternatives, and much more!
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#landing-page {
  background-color: dimgray;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  min-height: 396px; }

h1 {
  font-size: 10vmin;
  color: #FFF; }

h5 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }

h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }

/* MORE THAN 75 (XL) */
#middle-row {
  height: 95%; }

/* LESS THAN 75 (LG) */
@media (max-width: 74.9em) {
  #middle-row {
    height: 95%; } }
/* LESS THAN 62 (MD) */
@media (max-width: 61.9em) {
  #middle-row {
    height: 75%; } }
/* LESS THAN 48 (SM) */
@media (max-width: 47.9em) {
  #middle-row {
    height: 75%; } }
/* LESS THAN 34 (XS) */
@media (max-width: 33.9em) {
  #middle-row {
    height: 75%; } }

.navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #FFF; }

nav {
  background-color: #fc4747; }


  html, body {
  height: 100%; }
```

**EDIT** [new jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aqg1khLs/14/) which successfully replicates the issue

Comment: I can't see any white space.

Comment: We can't see the white space in the jsfiddle, the problem may be in the html / body tags.

Comment: @Leothelion Did my photos of the issue upload? I have a dodgy internet connection

Comment: no..we are not able to see any photos as they are coming from local but not from internet link.

Comment: Is it you are using MAC and checking in chrome browser?

Comment: Yes we can see the photos in the post.But we can't see images in the jsfiddle as you put a relative path from your website.

Comment: we don't need any images, this is issue with `css` and `height` of elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `CSS` if you want to specify `height` property using percents you **must** specify `height` of the parent container. so, in your case, your `#landing-page` element have its parents `<body>` tag, and `<body>` tag have its parent `<html>` tag. That's why you **must** state:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

in you css.

Another issue is here:

```
<div class="row hidden-lg-up" style="height:20%;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="row" style="height:95%;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="row" style="height:5%;">
    ...
</div>
```

try to sum all of the heights =) change it so they in sum will make 100% and you will get what you want

---

**UPDATE**

I've managed to reproduce your problem locally, so here is the solution.
Actually, you have issue not with white line at the bottom, the main culprit of the bottom while line is `margin-top` property of `#landing-page` element =).
Look, if you remove `<nav>` element, you will see the same white line at the top. It appears that you set up height of 100% for `#landing-page` and than shifted it to bottom. Browser than draws background at 100% of **visible** space, but, as you can notice, you have some vertical scroling and everything that is under that scroll doesn't have **background-color**.

In general, `margin`'s are tricky where it comes to `background-color` or `background-image` as it may lead to current (or similar) problem. Move `margin-top` value to `padding-top` value to have same spacing, than remove `calc()` from the `height` property, like this:

```
#landing-page {
  background-color: dimgray;
  height: 100%; /* just 100% */
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 60px 40px 10px 40px; /* added margin-top to padding-top */
  min-height: 396px; }
```

Comment: Thanks you are right about the heights adding to 100%. However my `body` and `html` elements already have height 100%, sorry. I forgot to add it to the question because I'm using angular 2 and that css for `html` and `body` is abstracted away into a file that I forgot about. I will add that info to the question. The white space at the bottom is still there. I'm thinking something in my environment is causing it. I'm on holiday on a remote island using my mobile phone as a wifi hotspot and experiencing some weird issues.

Comment: what browser do you use? In the chrome, there is no white space in the bottom when `html` and `body` is 100% height.

Comment: Can I access to your site through the web? Is it somewhere online?

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins, are you here?

Comment: I just got back online. I managed to replicate the issue in a new jsfiddle which I have posted in the question.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins, updated my answer with working solution

Answer (score 0):

In the jsfiddle we can't see the whitespace, so the problem may come from the html / body tags.
If they are always at 1155px no matter how much you resize, try setting the html and body height to 100% :

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background-color on `body` instead of a `div`, will solve your problem.

Comment: That makes the white space grey. But I want the white space to completely go away. So that there is no scrolling needed and the height of the page is 100% when including the navigation bar.

Comment: I see, but why are you using height: calc(100% - 50px); instead of just 100%?

Comment: Also try changing to padding rather than margin and apply box-sizing: border-box to #landing-page

Comment: using the height calculation because it goes below the navigation bar which is 50px, and it needs to end at the bottom of the viewport, not 50px below it. Thanks I will try that soon.

Comment: No the nav bar is fixed so it won't add to the height. Therefor you need to set the height to 100%